# error in plotting a function, including integrate.quad

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, quad

I want to plot a function which has `integrate.quad` in it. The function has true float value in the interval.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as integrate

def S(M):
    s = integrate.quad(lambda k: np.exp(-k) * np.sin(2 * M), 0, 5)[0]
    return s

M = np.arange(10, 20, 1)
plot = plt.plot(M, S(M))
plt.show()
```

But I receive this error:

> error: Supplied function does not return a valid float.

I don't know the reason the function has correct float value and I specified the first term of quad output with `[0]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`S()` is unable to handle vector input. Try to replace the line with the `plot()` by this:

```
plot = plt.plot(M, np.vectorize(S)(M))
```